# how to merge elements in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

trying to sort elements in dataframe according to requirement. I imported data from excel and use python/pandas to do analysis.

this is the data I collected, each correspond to index 1-4

```
 d   = {
        1:['0E', '1A', '1D', '2A']

        2:[ '0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A']

        3:[ '0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A', '3B']

        4:['1D', '1E']
       }
```

I expected to show like this:

```
[1D] index 1;2;3;4

[0E;1A;1D] index 1;2;3

[1E] index 2;3;4
```

how can i do that? I tried for loop for each i in dataframe but could solve this problem
thanks!

Comment: How does your actual data look like? Can you share `print(df.head())`?

Comment: @Chris it looks like a dictionary with values as list

Comment: @min2bro It does look like so, but given OP tag this as pandas, i'm still unsure of which approach would be the best.

Comment: @min2bro hi, thanks for comment. YES it is a dictionary with values as list. I tried to copy the print() to stackoverflow but for some reason it can not dispaly properly.

Comment: @weiyi what is the expected ouput type?

Comment: @min2bro prefer a list. but doesn't matter because i'll have to export to excel manually anyway.

Comment: @Chrisyes it is a dict with values as list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```py
import pandas as pd

data={1: ['0E', '1A', '1D', '2A'], 2: ['0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A'], 3: ['0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A', '3B'], 4: ['1D', '1E']}

data_mod = [[el, k] for k,v in data.items() for el in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_mod, columns=["el", "key"]) #el -> alphanumeric key, key -> [1,2,3,4], as per original dict keys

df_2 = df.groupby("el", as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ";".join([str(el) for el in list(set(x))])).groupby("key").agg(lambda x: list(x)) #final product, as per your question
```

Comment: I'm not quite understand about the logic, but gladly this code works!

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I understand your question (and the format of your input data) correctly, then:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0E', '1A', '1D', '2A'],[ '0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A'], [ '0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A', '3B'], ['1D', '1E']])
df.index = range(1, 5)

    0   1   2      3     4     5
1   0E  1A  1D     2A    None  None
2   0E  1A  1D     1E    2A    None
3   0E  1A  1D     1E    2A    3B
4   1D  1E  None   None  None  None

vals = np.unique(df.values.flatten()[~pd.isnull(df.values.flatten())])
```

Expand out the unique values of this original dataframe into a new dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1["vals"] = vals
df1["indices"] = [df[df == i].stack().index.get_level_values(0).values for i in vals]
```

Then `groupby` and `aggregate` to give:

```
df1.groupby("Indices").agg(lambda x: list(x))

            Vals
Indices 
[1 2 3 4]   [1D]
[1 2 3]     [0E, 1A, 2A]
[2 3 4]     [1E]
[3]         [3B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way

```py
d = {1: ['0E', '1A', '1D', '2A'],
 2: ['0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A'],
 3: ['0E', '1A', '1D', '1E', '2A', '3B'],
 4: ['1D', '1E']}

df = pd.DataFrame()

for key, value in d.items():
    for x in value:
        df.loc[key, x] = str(key)

df
Out[83]: 
    0E   1A 1D   2A   1E   3B
1    1    1  1    1  NaN  NaN
2    2    2  2    2    2  NaN
3    3    3  3    3    3    3
4  NaN  NaN  4  NaN    4  NaN
```